# Setting an IronPython variable to None

Tags: c#, ironpython

How can I set the value of a variable inside an IronPython scope to None from C# using `ScriptScope.SetVariable` without using `ScriptEngine.ExecuteAndWrap("x = None", scope)`? Does the variable need to already be defined within the ScriptEngine/ScriptScope? This example did not work:

```
// Note: "scope" is the ScriptScope variable assigned beforehand

scope.SetVariable("x", null);
```

web search found this related link but it did not provide a solution:
http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2009-June/010605.html

Comment: The var does not necessarily need to exist in the scope prior to calling SetVariable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the keyword `object` is just an alias for `System.Object`, but I found that casting `null` to `System.Object` worked in some cases.

```
scope.SetVariable("x", (Object)null);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did discover that the var does not necessarily need to exist in the scope prior to calling SetVariable.

Comment: Work like a charm